# RESTful API design: Items unread by user

Tags: rest

Designing a RESTful API with Users, Questions and Answers as my "nouns", I am unsure which URL makes the most sense for retreiving the (count of) unread Answers to the User's Questions.

Say, the current User (ID: 42) has asked 4 Questions, and since his last Login 2 answers were given to any of those questions.

What would be a sensible URL to retreive this number, 2?
I have thought about these (although scope is more relevant than wording in these examples)

- `/users/42/questions?feature=unread_anwers`
- `/answers?unread_by=42&question_owner=42` (which seems pretty unrestful to me)
- `/answers?since=<%USER:last_login%>&question_owner=42`
- `/users/42` (and have the unread_answers as a property of the user object)
- `/users/42/questions/answers?status=unread` (which would break the /noun/id/noun-Pattern)
- `/users/42/questions/all/answers?status=unread` (more towards the "right" pattern, but still seems wrong)
- any other sensible URL?

I am currently leaning towards the first suggestion, although I am still hesistating. I have been unable to find any Best-Practise-Ressources on this issue; and would like to know whether there is a right-ish way of designing this case.

Any opinion or direction-pointing will be appreciated!

**Edit:**
Colleagues of mine suggested ...

- `/users/42/unread_answers` (adds a pseudo-noun, which I think should not be)
- `/users/42/answers?status=unread` (breaks the hierarchy, as /users/42/answers should in fact return the answers given by user 42)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct option:

```
/users/42/questions/all/answers/unread
```

Each tier represents a single resource or a set of resources.
The main goal of REST is to have every URL be a unique identifier for a Resource.
As soon as you start putting query parameters in you break this goal and it just becomes `RPC` over `HTTP`. See ["This isn't REST this is RPC"](http://www.vertigrated.com/blog/2009/10/this-isnt-rest-this-is-rpc/) for more details.

Comment: To put what you are saying in different words: _query parameters are against REST (are breaking it)_. Right?

Comment: Although I would not go the length to say "any query parameters are breaking REST", I find Jarrods response quite sensible. Thanks!

Comment: Query parameters do not identify a resource; they are like arguments to a function call and end up making your call become RPC over HTTP.